# The graph of $y(x)=-x^2+bx+c$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

The graph of $y(x)=-x^2+bx+c$ is shown below. Determine the signs (+ or -) of $b$ and $c$.

[image]

$a=-1$ so the parabola opens downwards, but we can already see that from the given figure. How can we determine the sign of $b$ and $c$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! *Hint*: Use Vieta"s relations. Also, the maximum is attained at $x=-b/2a$.

Comment: Hint (for $c$): what happens to the equation if you set $x=0$? What point on the parabola corresponds to $x=0$?

Comment: Hint 2 (following silver's hint). What happens to y'(x) if you set x=0?

Comment: @Bernard, the coefficient $c$ is the height of the parabola where it intercepts the y-axis, so $c>0$. I don't see how we can use the Vieta's relations, tho. $$\begin{cases}x_1x_2=-c\\x_1+x_2=b\end{cases}$$ From the first $x_1$ and $x_2$ have different signs, but we already know that.

Comment: @user965851 Vieta's relations tell the sign of the mean of the two $x$-intercepts, which is also the $x$-coordinate of the turning point:

$$\frac{x_1+x_2}2 = -\frac{b}{2a}$$

(But I usually would just look at $y'(0)$ and $y(0)$ to determine the signs of $b$ and $c$)

Comment: One can observe there are two roots, with opposite signs. But using the sign of the $y$-intercept is fine too.